# Javascript change selectedIndex of a Select by its name

Tags: javascript, wordpress

I'm using a wordpress plugin which forces me to use the name="" attribute. So I can't change it to id="" or class="". When I click the button I want the selectedIndex for name="select" to be changed to 2.

Here's what I've tried:

```
<select name="select">
<option value="1">option1</option>
<option value="2">option2</option>
</select>
<input type="button" value="CHANGE" onclick="selectFunction()" />

var selectFunction = function() {
document.getElementById("select").selectedIndex = 2;
};
```

So I basically want to use this function using name="" and not id="". Which means something like document.getElementById("select").selectedIndex = 2; wont work.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: `document.getElementsByName('select')[0]`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use [`querySelector()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/document.querySelector) to select with a CSS style selector:

```
document.querySelector('select[name="select"]').selectedIndex = 2;
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/4exeJ/

Or if you needed to support old versions of IE that don't have `querySelector()` you could use `document.getElementsByTagName("select")` and then loop through the resulting list testing the `.name` of each until you found the right one.

Or there's the [`document.getElementsByName()` function](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/document.getElementsByName), which also returns a list (or an HTMLCollection), but according to [QuirksMode.org](http://quirksmode.org/dom/core/) it doesn't work properly in IE<=9.

Note that option indexes start at 0 (so in your example you don't want to set `selectedIndex` to 2 because the last option is index 1).

Answer (score 1):

Try this, You can use [getElementsByName](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/document.getElementsByName)

```
<select name="select">
```

Javascript:

```
document.getElementsByName("select")[0].selectedIndex = 1;
```

Comment: Like I mentioned my problem is that I cannot add id="".